# NOT NULL constraint failed: Adm_profile.user_id en django Allauth

Tags: python, django

tengo un problema el cual llevo rato buscando solución que quiero y de la cual no he podido encontrar, puesto que el error que me sale, se puede solucionar poniendo en el campo de "OneToOneField(null=True), pero al hacer eso mi sistema pierde una funcionalidad super importante, la función de relacionar el usuario que se esta creando en "Django.auth.User" con los campos personalizados que he creado, y al registrarte salta el siguiente error.

[image: El error que me salta]

Adm_profile.user_id es el campo en la base de datos que debe contener el "Id" del usuario registrado en "auth_user" para que los datos del Usuario creado por medio de "Auth" coincidan con los de mi formulario personalizado, pero me da error, al guardar los datos, si pongo en el campo de OneToOneField null=True, se quita el error, pero no me deja guardar el user_id para que hagan coincidir ambas tablas :(. Como les comento, he buscado demasiado y no encuentro una solución :(.

Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Matricula = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

forms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from django.forms import ModelForm
 from models import *
 from django.db import models

 #create your forms here


class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'Matricula')

      #Saving user data
   def signup(self, request, user):
       user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
       user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
       user.Matricula = self.cleaned_data['Matricula']
       user.save()

       ##Save profile

       profile = Profile()
       Profile.user = user
       profile.Matricula = self.cleaned_data['Matricula']
       profile.save()
```

En mi settings.py agregue esta linea para agregar los campos personalizados en el formulario que viene en Allauth

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'Adm.forms.SignupForm'
```

[image: En la base de datos]
Como se puede ver, no me guarda el user_id que se creo en la tabla auth_user y así no puedo acceder a los atributos que tiene ese usuario.

Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme, soy estudiante y es mi proyecto final, he investigado mucho, leyendo la documentación, tutoriales en ingles, pero no me ha funcionado. 
Python es un lenguaje maravilloso <3

Si necesitan info adicional, solo díganme, aún sigo aprendiendo Django, es algo nuevo para mi

Comment: Lastimosamente no manejo Django, pero dime. Es Adm_profile una tabla en tu base de datos? No lo veo definido en tu código. O es el nombre de algun `constraint`.

Comment: Ahora que veo la segunda imagen, efectivamente es una tabla. Pero no veo donde lo estas mapeando en tu código. Me parece que esos datos estan siendo insertados al llamar `user.save()`. Si es asi no veo donde estas asignas el valor `user_id`. Podrias colocar el codigo donde defines esa clase?

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas la definicion completa de tus tablas (las implicadas) y retires la segunda imagen. Es inherente al error que estas teniendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @miso, logre resolverlo en el transcurso del día, después de tanto leer, tanto buscar, tanto de todo encontré que la parte de forms.py tenía que poner profile en minúscula para que se guardara el usuario, lo probé y funciono todo correcto, solo por una letra mi sistema no funcionaba :(. Pero en verdad, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tiempo e interes.